# Java need help linking two frames to use the same object and restarting util . timer

Tags: java, object, user-interface, timer

Hi everyone I'm really stuck on this and could use some help.
So basically I have a Tamagotchi - style game with JProgress bars which decrease using a method which utilises the java.util.Timer. In my class for the game GUI I declare an object from the pet class giving it null values which are then input by the user at the start of the game using JOptionPane. This is why I can't restart the entire game as it will lose all attributes for the pet.

Now my problem is I need to create a shop for the game where the user can buy things to affect the game. I'm not sure how to use the same object from the shop gui class. I've tried created an accessor method for the object but it dosen't seem to affect the pet's states.

```
dr.getDragonObject().setHunger(150); //dr is called as private PetInterface dr;
```

Also when I cancel the timer I cannot restart it when I click to go back to the game. I've tried calling a resetTimer() method in the ActionListener after setting the current timer to a new one.

Comment: you need to call `setHunger()` on the same Object like in the first GUI, otherwise it will not affect stats. For the timer, you can stop the first one and start a new one

Comment: I know that but I have no idea how to actually code that.

Comment: you could use Singleton-Pattern to store 1 instance of your pets: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html